# Firefox 123 on Ubuntu 22.04 - theme - colour.css missing

Tags: 22.04, firefox

I'm running the Firefox v123 snap on Ubuntu 22.04. When starting in normal mode, the browser is not rendering webpages. I get a translucent window with confused mesh of pixels from the web page it should be rendering.

Starting from console reveals an error message when parsing gtk.css.

```
~$ firefox --safe-mode
[Parent 29743, Main Thread] WARNING: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:21: Failed to import: Error opening file /home/emma/snap/firefox/3941/.config/gtk-3.0/colors.css: No such file or directory: 'glib warning', file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp:187

(firefox:29743): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:49:17.909: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1:21: Failed to import: Error opening file /home/emma/snap/firefox/3941/.config/gtk-3.0/colors.css: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: 13:49:17.924: Failed to load module "window-decorations-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 13:49:17.925: Failed to load module "colorreload-gtk-module"
```

This version of firefox snap works in safe-mode when started from the console.

I have tried:

1. Changing the theme without logging out but this has no effect.
2. Removing and reinstalling the snap
3. Changing which profile via the ProfileManager in safe-mode
4. Loading an older version, which worked for a reason I cannot guess.
5. Searching the root directory for a file named colors.css, which returned some old files called public-colors.css

Firefox was starting reliably until a week or so ago. I do not know when Firefox v123 was loaded by snap from the latest/stable channel.

- Is this a known bug?
- Has it been reported on the Mozilla Bugzilla?
- Is there a fix or workaround?

Comment: After some further experiments I can only conclude that there is a defect in the construction of the snap package, which may not be relevant to this forum (hence the -1 rating I presume).  Thank you Karel for reformatting my question.

I have loaded Firefox v123 without using a snap as my workaround.  This installation arrangement works well and will do for now.

I have raised this issue on the Mozilla Support page hoping it will be helpful.